# Use Intention OR Intention of use?

Tags: expression-choice

I carry out a marketing survey about a new service, and I wonder what is the most appropriate expression (for a british public) :

"The use intention" OR "The intention of use" ?

The question was "Do you intend to use this service".

I have the same issue with this expression :

"Equipments purchase intention" OR "Purchase intention of equipments" OR "Equipments intention of purchase" ?

These expressions refer to a rate. In my power point document, I have a slide with this sentence : 83% of respondents intend to use the service.

And I need to choose the right expression to illustrate (for the title) this sentence : is it "The use intention" or "The intention of use" ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: I don't fully understand what you are trying to convey with "Equipments purchase intention", etc., but I think it sounds like you mean "Intent to purchase equipment"? Also I think the question might be better suited to [ell.sx](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: None of them sounds right. I'd suggest *"intention to use"* and *"intention to purchase equipment"*.

Comment: "*None of them sounds right*" doesn't sound right either?

Comment: In the context of a Power Point presentation, I present statistical results of a survey. So I need the right expression for the title : could I use "Intention to use" as an expression ?

Answer (score 3):

After asking the question "Do you intend to use this service?"

The follow-up question you're looking for it:

> What is the **intended use**?

Or

> **How** do you intend to use this service?

is also common.

The second part of your question is very similar, just relating to "equipment":

> Equipment's intended use

or

> Reason for equipment purchase